# Приведите пример кода сравнения двух изображений в OpenCv2 C++ (4.3.0)

Tags: c++, opencv

Все книги устарели, мануалы тем более. Стандартные примера с сравнением через хэш изображения стали невозможными, ибо в новых версиях их удалили(хотя в документации остались).

Если у вас есть код сравнения двух изображений реализованных на OpenCv, то прошу привести в пример, ибо сам не могу найти ничего уж слишком много времени.

Изображения имеют одинаковый тип/размер/цветовой фильтр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно сравнивать только **два** изображения на полную идентичность, никакой хэш не нужен.

Сравните размеры и формат

Выполните вычитание изображений или `bitwise_xor`, и посчитайте, есть ли ненулевые пикселы в результате `countNonZero`.